# How to check if session type is user or admin or employee in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to show the sidebar according to login session type.
here in if condition ,if i use single type then it work,but if i use OR(||) operator in if condition then it not work,it means if i apply if condition for user and admin only then if employee is login this menu is shows.

my view

```
<?php
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');
    $type = $session_data['type'];
?>

<aside class="main-sidebar">    
    <section class="sidebar">
    <?php if ($type == 'Employee' || 'admin') { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admin/emp_requsition"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Employees Requsitions</span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'User' || 'admin') { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admin/pending_list"><i class="fa fa-list "></i> <span>Pending Lists</span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'admin') { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admin/view_reports"><i class="fa fa-list "></i> <span>View Report</span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admin/chage_passwords"><i class="fa fa-lock  "></i> <span>Change Password</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <span>Logout</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "if" condition must be like this:

```
<?php if ($type == 'Employee' || $type == 'admin') { ?>
```

I would also change the use of "{" by ":". Here's an example:

```
<?php if ($type == 'Employee' || $type == 'admin'): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admin/emp_requsition"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Employees Requsitions</span></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think is more readable and clean, but this is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You cant write your condition like `<?php if ($type == ('Employee' || 'admin')) { ?>`

you have to write it:
`<?php if (($type == 'Employee') || ($type == 'admin')) { ?>`

so the whole block:

```
<section class="sidebar">
    <?php if (($type == 'Employee') || ($type == 'admin')) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admin/emp_requsition"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Employees Requsitions</span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'User' || $type == 'admin') { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admin/pending_list"><i class="fa fa-list "></i> <span>Pending Lists</span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'admin') { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admin/view_reports"><i class="fa fa-list "></i> <span>View Report</span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admin/chage_passwords"><i class="fa fa-lock  "></i> <span>Change Password</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <span>Logout</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition like this

```
<?php if ($type == 'Employee' || $type == 'admin') { ?>
```